# Codeigniter View with controller within View (with a Controller) when loading the 2nd view the 1st view data are erased

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter, view, ready

SECOND VIEW

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var GlobalVariables = {
    'csrfToken'     : <?php echo json_encode($this->security->get_csrf_hash()); ?>,
    'baseUrl'       : <?php echo '"' . $base_url . '"'; ?>,
    'dateFormat'    : <?php echo json_encode($date_format); ?>,
    'services'      : <?php echo json_encode($services); ?>,
    'categories'    : <?php echo json_encode($categories); ?>,
    'user'          : {
        'id'        : <?php echo $user_id; ?>,
        'email'     : <?php echo '"' . $user_email . '"'; ?>,
        'role_slug' : <?php echo '"' . $role_slug . '"'; ?>,
        'privileges': <?php echo json_encode($privileges); ?>
    }
  };

  $(document).ready(function() {
    BackendServices.initialize(true);
  });
</script>
  <div>some contenent</div>
```

so this is the view that i would like to integrate within this view

FIRST VIEW

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var GlobalVariables = {
    'csrfToken'     : <?php echo json_encode($this->security->get_csrf_hash()); ?>,
    'baseUrl'       : <?php echo '"' . $base_url . '"'; ?>,
    'dateFormat'    : <?php echo json_encode($date_format); ?>,
    'userSlug'      : <?php echo '"' . $role_slug . '"'; ?>,
    'settings'      : {
        'system'    : <?php echo json_encode($system_settings); ?>,
        'user'      : <?php echo json_encode($user_settings); ?>
    },
    'user'          : {
        'id'        : <?php echo $user_id; ?>,
        'email'     : <?php echo '"' . $user_email . '"'; ?>,
        'role_slug' : <?php echo '"' . $role_slug . '"'; ?>,
        'privileges': <?php echo json_encode($privileges); ?>
    }
};



$(document).ready(function() {
    BackendSettings.initialize(true);

});
</script>

<div>Sidebar..
  ...
       <div id="#loading-view" > a tab in the side bar</div>
 </div>
```

I found similar case to mine but their views were without controller
 i tried this in the FIRST VIEW Controller (the view that have the side bar)

```
 $('.tab').click(function() {
   $('#loading').load(GlobalVariables.baseUrl + '/index.php/backend/services');
```

but when loading the second view in the loading div the data of the other tab are erased or something like that 
. I know that the problem is in the .ready() ajax function 
because when i read about it, it load the entire view or something like that
but when I comment the ready() function in the SECOND VIEW the css apear without data .

so please has anyone had this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

jQuery `element.load()` will replace the content of the element every time.
to load a view inside parent view you need to load its content to a child div inside the parent view.

**HTML**

```
<div id="parentView">
   <div id="childView"></div>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$('.tab').click(function() {
       $('#parentView').load(GlobalVariables.baseUrl + '/index.php/backend/services');
       $('#childView').load(GlobalVariables.baseUrl + '/index.php/backend/services');    
});
```

Comment: it works but i have allways the same problem when i switch from view it dosen't work
i read about turbo link or something like that ! have an idea about it ?